# How to delete an unpackaged app from HoloLens 2

Tags: hololens

I'm having trouble deleting an app from HL2 which was deployed directly from Visual Studio.

I want to delete it because i want to deploy a packaged version through Device Portal.

Obviously it gives an error message:

> Failure reason: Another user has already installed an unpackaged
> version of this app. The current user cannot replace this with a
> packaged version. The conflicting package is AppName and it was
> published by CN=CompanyName. Failure text: The provided package is
> already installed, and reinstallation of the package was blocked.
> Check the AppXDeployment-Server event log for details. (0x80073cfb)

So i have tried to delete it on Device Portal, but there is an error message again:

> Failed to uninstall package AppName_1.0.0.0_arm64__...

I have tried to delete it directly from the HoloLens, the app icon disappers from the HoloLens, but the application is still in the **Installed Apps** list. (And i cannot deploy the packaged version)

Is there a way to force delete an application?

HoloLens2 OS version: 20348.1518.arm64fre.fe_release_svc_sydney_rel_prod.220906-1328

UPDATE:

On the Device Portal, when i want to remove the app i get response on DELETE *api/app/packagemanager/package?package=AppName...*  with code 500 and body

```
{"Code" : -2147009295, "CodeText" : "Package was not found.\r\n", "Reason" : "Windows cannot remove AppName_1.0.0.0_arm64__... because the current user does not have that package installed. Use Get-AppxPackage to see the list of packages installed.", "Success" : false}
```

Comment: Does the app still exist in **Settings->Apps->Installed apps** on the HoloLens? Have you tried restarting the HoloLens device? And is there any more error message about the uninstall failure? For example, you can check whether some messages are returned in the browser console.

Comment: It's not in the Installed apps on the HoloLens. Yes, i've tried it. I've updated the question with the error message from the Device Portal.

Comment: Did you use different accounts for the two deployments? If so, please switch to the same account and try again. If it still doesn't work, you may need to reset the device - [Restart, reset, or recover HoloLens 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-recovery).

Comment: I'm not sure if i used different accounts for the depolyments, but i've tried to delete the app from both without success. I've already thought about reseting the HL but i've wanted to avoid that. 
Thanks for your help!
P.S. Can we expect a fix on it in a Windows update in the near future?

Comment: This issue cannot be reproduced and tracked, so we cannot determine whether it is related to the OS version. But if this application does not affect your development and use, you can ignore it, for the packaged version you want to deploy, you only need to modify its package version number.